# Localhost wamp allow access to PC from LAN but Not from WAN

Tags: localhost, router, portforwarding

I want to make my pc a remote server. i am using wamp server and put it online. when am accessing my pc through another pc in LAN it will work but when i am accessing my pc through the other PC which is not in my LAN it pop-up a login authentication form. it ask for username or password. the below line is appearing

"A username and password are being requested by XXXXX The site says: "110TC1"

what i am doing wrong ????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a network like this

```
 Internet
    |
  Router 
    |
   / \
  /   \
PC1   PC2
```

Local network has 3 interfaces, PC1, PC2 and internal Router port. This interfaces has private IP addresses like 192.168.1.1.

External network (internet) has public IP address. When you try to connect over internet, with public IP address you receive an answer from your router, not from your PC. Try to make a [port forwarding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) for your pc IP address via your router configuration page.

Comment: with my public IP or Private IP ?

Comment: Port forwarding for a specific port of your public IP to your PC private IP at port 80. Check your user manual of your router for how to do this.

Comment: thankyou miltos. now i am able to access my pc from WAN with my pc's ip address. but now i want to access my pc by domain not ip .

Comment: You are able to access your PC with your public IP. This IP is dynamic or static? If you have a static IP address try to assign a domain to this address. If you have a dynamic IP address try to use a free/paid [dynamic dns service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS) that supported from your router for dynamic updating.

Answer (score 0):

you need to forward the ports from your router to the local IP of the machine.

access your router via 192.168.1.1 from your browser

I don't know your router make or model so you will need to google it.

But you want a port forwarding option.

Cheers,
Ant.